# Optionally load Firebase module in Angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm working on an Angular app that is intended to be deployed in multiple Firebase projects. I'm using AngularFire. When serving apps, Firebase makes its packages available via a reserved hosting URL. So I'm doing this in index.html:

```
<script src="/__/firebase/7.14.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
<app-root></app-root>
```

And I'm doing this in app.module.ts:

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
...
imports: [AngularFireModule]
```

And I'm doing this in main.ts, where `environment.firebase` is a valid Firebase config:

```
function getConfig(): Observable<any> {
  return environment.production ? getConfigFromReservedURL() : of(environment.firebase);
}

function getConfigFromReservedURL(): Observable<any> {
  return from(fetch('/__/firebase/init.json').then(response => response.json()));
}

getConfig()
  .subscribe(
    config => platformBrowserDynamic([{ provide: FIREBASE_OPTIONS, useValue: config }])
      .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
  );
```

`ng serve` works fine here. `ng build --prod --aot` gets the config correctly from `/__/firebase/init.json`.

But when I `firebase deploy` to the server, I get the warning:
"@firebase/app: Warning: Firebase is already defined in the global scope. Please make sure Firebase library is only loaded once."

That is happening because I used `npm install firebase` to install the Firebase dependency so that normal imports could work within the app, such as `import { auth } from 'firebase/app';`. So Typescript is compiling the Firebase SDK into the app. But the SDK NEEDS to be initialized via the script element; I don't want the SDK initialization to be baked into the app besides.

How do I tell the build process to treat the Firebase SDK like an ambient module when building the app for production, while keeping it available as a normal package for `ng serve`?

Answer (score 1):

A co-worker helped me to find what was wrong. This code isn't needed in index.html:

```
<script src="/__/firebase/7.14.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

Firebase's [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls) says that 'In addition to hosting the SDKs themselves, the reserved namespace also provides all of the configuration necessary to initialize the SDK for the Firebase project associated with the Hosting site. This Firebase configuration and SDK initialization is provided by a script that you can include directly...' It does provide all of the configuration necessary, but you don't actually need that in Angular if you have installed the Firebase package via NPM.